# Batch or Cancel Processing of Azure Service Queue

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

How do I cancel processing or process a specified number of queue messages for an Azure Service Bus Queue using the DotNet SDK without the Delivery Count going up? Increasing the Delivery count causes things to go into a dead letter message

Following [these directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) using QueueClient instead of SubscriptionClient I was able to write two console apps, a sender and a receiver of Service Bus Queues. If I want to process things in the queue in batch (eg. Every minute I want to process 100 Queue Items or every Minute request 100 Queue items) how would I gracefully cancel the processing that's happening after calling RegisterMessageHandler(event, cancellationToken)?

---

```
//throws System.OperationCanceledException exception so the DeliveryCount goes up
await queueClient.CloseAsync(); 
//throws Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageNotFoundException exception so DeliveryCount also goes up 
await queueClient.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber);
```

I tried following the [prefetch best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#prefetching) but that seems to only act as a "buffer" of how many it requests not a total batch.

Answer (score 0):

`CancelScheduledMessageAsync()` is a wrong API to use as it's not cancelling processing.

When messages are retrieved by a client delivery count will be always increased. No matter if message was successfully processed or processing got cancelled. The only operation that will not increase delivery count is picking, but then you can't lock message for processing.

What I would recommend is look at how to configure `MaxDeliveryCount` to accommodate processing that can be cancelled.